# Ansible read file and filter

Tags: shell, file, ansible

I have a txt file like:

```
test1:group1:real name1
test2:group1:real name2
test3:group2:real name3
test4:group2:real name4
```

and I want to use it as an Ansible variable for a shell.

`- shell: test.sh -u {{ username }} -g {{ group }} -r {{ real_name }}`

With lookup, I was able to get a line from the file such as `test1:group1:real name1` However, I am not sure how to separate name or group.

`file_lines: "{{ lookup('file', './files/user.txt').splitlines() }}"`

Is there a way to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string into a list with [split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
- shell: test.sh -u {{ username }} -g {{ group }} -r {{ real_name }}
  loop: "{{ lookup('file', './files/user.txt').splitlines() }}"
  vars:
    params: "{{ item.split(':') }}"
    username: "{{ params[0] }}"
    group: "{{ params[1] }}"
    real_name: "{{ params[2] }}"
```

<sup>You can, of course, write it in a single line, depending on how readable you want your code to be.</sup>